# At what rate do O-Powers level up?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've noticed they seem to level up after X uses. If this is correct, how many uses does it take to get the next level?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need somewhere between 10 and 20 uses of Lvl 1 to unlock Lvl 2. Not sure about unlocking Lvl 3, though.

Comment: I am also curious about this. Can I spam the level 1 power to get it to level 3?

Answer (score 9):

To get from level 1 to level 2 you have to use the power 15 times. To get from level 2 to level 3 you have to use the(level 2) power 30 times. It appears using the level one power does NOT level up to level 3 - once you've reached level 2, you have to use level 2 to progress.